# How can I route a tomcat webapp to be the root of the site, preferably on a different port

Tags: tomcat

I have created an static angular app from before, and I want to deploy it on a tomcat server. Up until now, I have created a separate web app for it and successfully hosted it to `x.x.x.x:8080/frontend/`. I want it so that I can access it from the root URL, `x.x.x.x/`, preferably on a http/https port. I have plans for later linking it to a domain, but first I think I will need to get it to root URL.

I tried editing the META_INF/context.xml by adding `<Context path="">` and renamed the web app name to "ROOT" (replacing the old one by renaming it to "admin-panel"), though it still doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track by re-naming your application `ROOT`. Is this a directory called `ROOT` or a WAR file called `ROOT.war`? You should remove the `path` from your `<Context>` and allow Tomcat to determine the application's context-path from the WAR/directory name (e.g. `ROOT`).

Once you have that working, listening on port :80 is a separate topic which has been covered elsewhere on StackOverflow.